# fdopen and fprintf

Tags: c, file-descriptor

The following code is expected to write "some text" to demo.txt, but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int fd;

    if ((fd = open("demo.txt", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }
    fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "some text\n");
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are u sure if demo.txt file exists?

Comment: Yes, sure, and dprintf(fd, "some text\n") works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `fflush(fp)` to clear the buffer before closing the file.

When you write to the file descriptor `fp`, the data is buffered. 
But you are closing the file with `close(fd)` before the buffered data can be written written to the file `demo.txt`. Hence, buffered data is lost.
If you do `fflush(fp)`, it will ensure the buffered data is written to demo.txt immediately.

You should not call `close()` before doing `fclose()` for all the opened files.

Proper way is to do `fclose(fp)` first and then do `close(fd)`.

Comment: Note that this is just a hack. The code has multiple problems, as outlined in my answer; most importantly the file descriptor `fp` depends on is getting closed.

Comment: You should never call `close` on a file descriptor that was passed to `fdopen`, because closing the `FILE` stream will flush and close it again, even though the same file descriptor may have been assigned a new use. This is very dangerous; it could corrupt other files you have opened. If you want to be able to `close` the original fd safely, you should call `dup` before passing it to `fdopen` and use the duplicate descriptor with `fdopen`.

Comment: And I forgot to mention, even if you don't call `fclose` at all, all `FILE` streams are implicitly closed at exit.

Answer (score 2):

The mode flag passed to `fdopen()` must be compatible with the mode of the file descriptor. The file descriptor's mode is `O_RDWR`, but you're doing:

```
fp = fdopen(fd, "w");
```

That might not work (it's undefined behavior.) Instead, open in `"r+"` mode:

```
fp = fdopen(fd, "r+");
```

Alternatively, use `O_WRONLY` for the file descriptor:

```
open("demo.txt", O_WRONLY)
```

Then you can `fdopen()` in `"w"` mode.

Finally, close the `FILE` structure instead of closing the file descriptor:

```
fclose(fp);
```

If you don't do that, `fp` loses its underlying file descriptor. You must not try to close the file descriptor manually after that. `fclose()` does that on its own.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, does (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT) corresponds to fdopen(fd, "a") ?

Comment: No. With "a" you can only write at the end of the file. Even if you seek elsewhere, you can't write anywhere else than at the end. That corresponds to O_APPEND.

Answer (score 1):

Use fclose(fp) instead of close(fd)